# Android C2DM sleeping phone

Tags: android, android-c2dm

According to [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_profilepage&v=PLM4LajwDVc#t=854s) Android C2DM keeps a socket alive with a heartbeat mechanism, making it able to receive push messages. This made me hope I could deliver messages to sleeping phones with an active wifi connection.

I've made an implementation setting the "delay_while_idle" to '0'. The message is delivered if my phones' screen is powered off, but not if the phone goes to sleep (tested with intervals 20mins, 1-6 hours).

I have acquired a partial cpu lock + a full wifi lock just in case.

Have I simply made something fundamentally wrong or did I misunderstand the C2DM push functionality?

Can I send messages to sleeping phones or not?

Comment: You can send messages to sleeping phones, yes, but there are a few issues and caveats. Make sure you're getting a wake lock in your receiver, and see this thread for a bit more info: http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm/browse_thread/thread/31a3fcae20a8267c

Comment: This seems to be the solution then:

" All,

I think that android 2.3 will allow developers to workaround this problem.
I'm the author of a SIP application (CSipSimple - search on googlecode ;) ). 
And reading the source of the Android 2.3 SIP stock application I noticed that they use a new type of wifi lock ....
It's : WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF  (int 3)."

Comment: Did you try changing the Wi-Fi sleep policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using alarmmanager instead of wakelocks could keep your phone alive just enough. See this [implementation](http://devtcg.blogspot.com/2009/01/push-services-implementing-persistent.html). Will test a variant of this.